# how to fix this error: Cannot find module 'moz' Nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I installed this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/moz-api Then when I try to run following code with key & id

```
var Moz = require('moz')
 
// initialize and configure client
const moz = new Moz({
  accessId: ACCESS_ID, 
  secretKey: SECRET_KEY
});
 
// fetch url metrics for moz.com
// return promise
moz.urlMetrics
  .fetch('moz.com', {
    cols: ['Title', 'Domain Authority'],
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.response.data)
  })
```

I get the following error:

```
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'moz'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\js\test.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\js\test.js:1:11)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [ ←[32m'C:\\Users\\Blouch\\Desktop\\js\\test.js'←[39m ]
}
```

I have no experience with npm whatsoever so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to require `moz-api` module

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This package Working with your method  after require call changing https://www.npmjs.com/package/moz-api-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the require call to

```
var Moz = require('moz-api')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This package Working with your method  after require call changing https://www.npmjs.com/package/moz-api-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! after changing `require moz-api` Now this error has occurred.

```
C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\node_modules\moz-api\lib\moz-endpoint.js:117
      if (!utils.hasProperty(this._moz.bitFlags[type], key)) {
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bitFlags' of undefined
    at applyArgs._validateColType (C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\node_modules\←[4mmoz-api←[24m\lib\moz-endpoint.js:117:40)
    at C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\node_modules\←[4mmoz-api←[24m\lib\moz-endpoint.js:133:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at applyArgs._validateCols (C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\node_modules\←[4mmoz-api←[24m\lib\moz-endpoint.js:132:34)
    at applyArgs.validate (C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\node_modules\←[4mmoz-api←[24m\lib\endpoints\url-metrics.js:39:10)
    at applyArgs.fetch (C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\node_modules\←[4mmoz-api←[24m\lib\endpoints\url-metrics.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Blouch\Desktop\jss\index.js:12:4)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)←[39m
```